# Error occurred running Grails CLI: No profile found for name [web]. (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

Tags: intellij-idea, grails

I am getting this error while trying to import a grails 3.3.2 project into intellij. I have searched online solutions and not found anything helpful.

Answer (score 35):

I found a solution to this question on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37125794/grails-run-app-execution-failed-for-task-bootrun-error-failed-to-start-ser) thread. Solution is just to delete the build folder and rebuild the project

Answer (score 6):

for me just delete the  build folder and rebuild the project and it worked

Answer (score 5):

As per below thread, I deleted the "build/.dependencies" file and it worked after resolving the dependencies again.

https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10898

Answer (score 5):

Just delete the build folder and rebuild the project.

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
export GRAILS_OPTS="-XX:-UseSplitVerifier -Xverify:none"
```

Comment: Can you add some context?

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

One potential cause is a mismatch of your defined profiles:

build.groovy:
`profile "org.grails.profiles:angular"`

application.yml: `grails.profile: web`

Make sure these agree with each other.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting `build` directory may work in most cases, but using the Gradle `clean`  task is the recommended and best practice approach for cleaning the build in a Grails application. It ensures consistency, safety, and compatibility with the Gradle build system.

You can call it either from command line:

```
gradlew clean
```

or from your IDE:

[image]

Here are some arguments why it's a better approach:

1. **Standardization**: Using the `gradle clean` command ensures a standardized and consistent way of cleaning the build. It's a well-defined task that is widely used in the Gradle ecosystem.
2. **Dependency Management**: The `gradle clean` command is aware of project dependencies, and it can clean the build artifacts and caches accordingly. Manually deleting the `build` directory might leave behind some cached files, leading to potential issues or outdated build results.
3. **Task Safety**: Gradle's `clean` task is designed to be safe and reliable. It only deletes files related to the build process, preserving other essential project files and directories.
4. **Automation**: By using `gradle clean`, users can integrate it into their build automation process, making it part of the regular development workflow. This ensures that the project starts from a clean state before every build.
5. **Ease of Use**: The `gradle clean` command is simple and easy to remember. It eliminates the risk of accidentally deleting important files from the project.
6. **Team Collaboration**: Using the standard `gradle clean` command makes it easier for other team members to understand and contribute to the project. It reduces confusion and prevents potential issues caused by manual build deletions.
7. **Future Compatibility**: Gradle may evolve, and new features or improvements might be introduced in the `clean` task. By using the official Gradle command, users can benefit from these updates without any extra effort.